# react-native-config lib returns empty Config object

Tags: react-native, expo, environment-variables, react-native-config

I am having trouble using react-native-config in my React Native app. Here's my code:

app.js

```
import Config from 'react-native-config';
console.log(Config);
```

.env

```
SECRET_KEY="kndlknv94ii4rpp"
```

The console.log statement in app.js returns an empty object. What am I doing wrong?

API keys should return on Config.SECRET_KEY but Config object itself returns an empty object

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because of your env file format. As in the [doc example](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#basic-usage), they are not using quotation marks. This might be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Did you do the "Extra Step For Android"  as mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#extra-step-for-android)?

The following needs to be added to `android/app/build.gradle`.  Make sure to add it on the 2nd line.

```
// 2nd line, add a new apply:
apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"
```

Comment: OMG. Thanks!! This step should be more visible in the docs, not under the "optional linking setup" instructions...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Expo you do not need any other libraries like react-native-dotenv or react-native-config. Just make sure your environment variables follow this format: `EXPO_PUBLIC_[NAME]=VALUE`. Then you will be able to access them using `process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_[NAME]`.

Answer (score -3):

Create a new file .env in the root of your React Native app:

```
API_URL=https://myapi.com
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY=abcdefgh
```

Then access variables defined there from your app:

```
import Config from "react-native-config";

Config.API_URL; // 'https://myapi.com'
Config.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY; // 'abcdefgh'
```

Documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-config).

Comment: Does not address the issue that OP is having and simply repeats what OP mentioned.

Comment: What's the issue actually you are facing @ssj_100?